# Need advice on writing For Loops differently in C, command line argument

Tags: c, cs50

I am looking to write a code where if a user enters a non digit command line argument, a message of "Usage: ./caesar key\n" pops up.

Currently I am able to only accept one command line argument which is good. Problem is when the user types multiple characters the  printf ("Success\n"); and printf ("%s\n", argv[1]); keeps repeating.

I also wanted that if the user enters for example: "12x" they get an error message of "Usage: ./caesar key" instead of looping through and giving me "success", "12x", "success", "12x" and "usage: ./caesar key".

For example:
~/workspace/pset2/caesar/ $ ./caesar 12x =>
Success
12x
Success
12x
Usage: ./caesar key

I want it to only be "Usage: ./caesar key" instead of all of them being printed out when there is even only a single non digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, string argv [])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        int n = strlen(argv[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(argv[1][i]))
            {
                 printf ("Success\n");
                 printf ("%s\n", argv[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you're asking? If I understand correctly, you need to check each command line argument for non-digit characters?

Comment: *keeps repeating*. Do you mean it never stops? The code as shown does print for every digit character. If you only want it to print once then put it outside the `for` loop and add a `return` in the first `else` case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I use to handle these situations:

- declare a `flag` variable initialized to `1` or `true` if you use `bool` type
- use the loop to check an unwanted condition and if it is satisfied you set `flag` to `0` or `false` and break the loop
- after the loop use the condition `if( flag )` to do something in case it was all right

```
int flag = 1;
    
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    if( !(isdigit(argv[1][i])) ) {
        
        printf ("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        flag = 0;
        break;
    }
}
    
if( flag ) {
        
    printf ("Success\n");
    printf ("%s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

You can of course name the `flag` as you prefer. `int onlyDigits = 1` with `if( onlyDigits )` would result in a more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was only working for **one** command line argument, given that the total arguments were **two**. To answer your question, you are also printing `Success` every time you find a character that is a digit, what you might want to do is check, if you want to go with that approach, if each character is **not** a digit, then you can terminate. You can also use `strspn()`, and check for a numbers in your string, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void usage(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: ...\n");
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int i = 1; /* Ignoring executable name */
    char *digits = "0123456789";

    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        for (; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if ((strlen(argv[i]) != strspn(argv[i], digits))) /* Checking if the length of the string is not equal to the matched numbers */
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid argument %s\n", argv[i]);
                usage();
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of arguments\n");
        usage();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, you check if the *length of your string* is not equal to the length of the `substring`which can contain any of the digits in string `digits`, if it is equal, you know that the string is actually made of only digits. More on `strspn()` [here](http://manpages.org/strspn) .